# How to use ESP8266 wifi shield as a hotspot?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

I have bought a ESP8266 wifi shield and I want to use it hotspot, I have tried the examples that have been provided in Arduino IDE, and the shield is getting connected to my network and giving me a wifi but without internet access (like I can connect my phone to the shield but I cannot browse the internet).
Any suggestion please?

Thanks......

Comment: What examples have you tried? Are you trying to get internet access onto your phone by going through the WiFi shield and Arduino? Where is the Arduino getting access to the Interent that it could then provide that to your phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting through the ESP8266 to the internet would require the ESP8266 to handle Network Address Traversal and/or routing, which is not officially supported.

However, if you are prepared to do a lot of work, it can be done. The performance and reliability is bad, but it can be done. See http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=960 Note that this will require far more skills than running the examples in the Arduino IDE.